# How to call method

Tags: c#, methods

My origanl DoWork Method was:

```
private static void DoWork(string dirPath)
```

which I called from my Main Method using:

```
DoWork(@"C:\location");
```

But I've changed the DoWork method to the following.

```
private static void DoWork(string sourceDir, string fileType)
```

I'm stumped how to call this from my main method, I am new to c# and have looked at the MSDN site but for some insight but I can't seem to find anything to relate to my issue. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Snippet from my DoWork method:

```
    private static void DoWork(string sourceDir, string fileType)
    {

        // Function: Get specified files (fileType) form sub-directory (sourceDir)
        // Return: void
            {
    string[] dirEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\fileDump");
    string fileName, filePath, fullFileName;

    foreach (string subDir in dirEntries)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(subDir);
    FileInfo[] imgFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.xml");

    foreach (FileInfo imgFile in imgFiles)
{
    fileName = imgFile.Name;
    filePath = imgFile.DirectoryName;
    fullFileName = "filePath + “\\” + fileName";
```

[Code From Here](http://devarea.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/how-to-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder-using-c/)

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match with the body - what's the question?  Are you asking how to call a method with multiple parameters?

Comment: If you change the signature of the DoWork method(two parameters instead of one), then you should pass two parameters when you call it. A bit of code for the DoWork method will help here. And, yes, as @Paolo says. What is the relation between your title and your question?

Comment: Really sorry, I was going to ask another question earlier today but found another solution for it. So as you can see I never changed the questionn title. I'm asking what you see in the question area please ignore the title.

Comment: Please see the code snippet above @Steve

Comment: How have you changed how you call DoWork from your main method? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I suppose, you want to call a method that works only on certain kind of files.
Then your code should be something like this

```
 private static void DoWork(string sourceDir, string fileType)
 {
      string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, fileType, 
                             SearchOption.AllDirectories);
      foreach (string fullFileName in fileEntries)
      {
            ....
      }
 }
```

and call it from the Main method in this way

```
 // Work on every JPG file in source location and subdirectory of the initial location
 DoWork(@"c:\location", "*.jpg");
```

The [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143316%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method could take three arguments that specify the source location, the file pattern to match files and an enum that triggers a recursive search of all subfolders of the initial folder.

Comment: I've popped all the code from my DoWork method so you can see exactly what I'm aiming for. I understand where your coming from however I need to process files in the sub directories so the solution using the overload will not work, I did try using this but it did not meet my requirments.

Comment: I'm sorry I take it all back, I have just tested you solution and it works perfectly. I can't think what I must of done something wrong last time I tried some thing similar. Thank you again.